# Implementing Event Subscription with Blazor ClientSide Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

Our Blazor App is running on `preview9`.

I am trying to implement a `.razor` component that listens to an event from a NotificationService we have written to refresh the view whenever the service is invoked, but I seem to be missing something;

I have my service Interface (reduced for brevity);

```
public interface INotificationService
{
    event Action OnChange;
    Task<ServiceResponse<Notification>> AddNotificationAsync(Notification notification);
}
```

and in my implementation I invoke the `OnChange` event (again reduced for brevity);

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<Notification>> AddNotificationAsync(Notification notification)
{
    /*...*/

    StateChanged();
}
```

Where `StateChanged()` is;

```
public event Action OnChange;

private void StateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
```

In my `Blazor.Client` I resolved `INotificationService` in `ConfigureServices` as follows;

```
services.AddScoped<INotificationService, NotificationService>();
```

I then inject the service into the component I want to subscribe to the `OnChange()` event;

```
 @inject INotificationService NotificationService

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     NotificationService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
 }
```

And then in my other `razor` page I again inject the same service and call the `AddNotificationAsync` method;

```
@inject INotificationService NotificationService

  await NotificationService.AddNotificationAsync(
                            new Notification { 
                                Level = NotificationLevel.Success, 
                                Text = $"Agreement Type with Id = {agreementType.Id} has been successfully added.".ToString()
                            });
```

However, calling t `NotificationService.AddNotificationAsync` is not triggering the `OnChange` and then the `StateHasChanged` of the component, as the component is not refreshing? Any ideas what I am doing wrong here please?

Comment: I'm attempting to implement something similar. Doesn't registering the dependency as scoped mean it's per request and therefore another page cannot affect it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following Microsoft docs [Invoke component methods externally to update state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state), you should to change:

```
 @inject INotificationService NotificationService

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     NotificationService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
 }
```

By:

```
 @inject INotificationService NotificationService

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     NotificationService.OnChange += OnNotify;
 }


 public async Task OnNotify()
 {
    await InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    });
 }
```

In your code, you are invoking the component's `StateHasChanged` method outside of Blazor's SynchronizationContext.

> InvokeAsync is used to switch to the correct context and queue a render.