# Update a field in Blazor from another component immediately

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, bind

I have an object (element) created on the parent component. And I pass a reference to it on child `ViewComponent` and child `EditComponent`.

When I change the element's properties in the `EditComponent`

```
<input type=text @bind=@Element.Placeholder/>
```

they change, but changes are shown on the `ViewComponent` only if I change focus.

I tried `<input type=text @bind=@Element.Placeholder @bind:event="oninput"/>` but nothing happened.

On the ViewComponent I show the result simply `<p>@Element.Placeholder`

I was wondering if I can get the `ViewComponent` to "listen" to changes, not hard rendering the values or something like that. No sure I'm using correct terms here hope you understood what I'm trying to do. Thanks
*Edited for clearer question

Comment: Can you please share some code or small example how you tried to achieve this with ```@bind:event="oninput"```?

Comment: Consider events - look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080747/implementing-event-subscription-with-blazor-clientside-application

Comment: @ZsoltBendes <input type=text @bind=@Element.Placeholder bind:event="oninput"/> i thought maybe this would work. On the ViewComponent there is no input just a <p>@Element.Placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  works for me
ViewComponent.razor

```
<p>@Value</p>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<ViewComponent Value="@_value" />
<input @bind="_value" @bind:event="oninput">

@code
{
    private string _value = "";
}
```

This should word with in a an `EditForm`.
You can try it out here in [fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/8c1rq3me).